# How can i install windowscodecs using wine 1.5.19?

Tags: wine, winetricks

I'm having a hard time trying to install windowscodecs.dll with winetricks.
I wish to install it in order to play "Star Wars: Knights of the Old Republic". 
Just installing the game won't work. A message from wine says that this dll is necessary.

So, using winetricks, i get:
"Note: command 'wine wic_x86_enu.exe /passive' returned status 67. Aborting."

I've tried to download the dll and place it in the system folder, inside drive C, in .wine, and inside the game folder. Doesn't make any difference, wine still requires the dll.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step: **$ winetricks windowscodecs**
its add override for windowscodecs.dll and registry patch.
Second step: extract windowscodecs.dll from **wic_x86_enu.exe** 
into **~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32** for 32-bit wine
or into **~/.wine/drive_c/windows/syswow64** for 64-bit wine

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second step? I know the location of ```/home/user/.cache/winetricks/windowscodecs/wic_x86_enu.exe```, but I don't know what you mean by "extract ```windowscodecs.dll``` from ```wic_x86_enu.exe```"

Comment: it means `cabextract ~/.cache/winetricks/windowscodecs/wic_x86_enu.exe`